# Change image from other classes in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm developing some apps for windows phone using c# but I have some troubles trying to pass some data (textblocks, images etc) from the MainPage to other classes.

I can explain it better saying:

I have MainPage.xaml + MainPage.xaml.cs (where my image is called "myImage"). This is the xaml code:

```
<Image  Name="myImage" DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

and using buttons in this class I can change the image simply typing:

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/xxxx.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

and it works.

I have an another class "x.cs" and I want to change the image when something happends, but how can I can access myImage from this class and change its Source without using timers? I've searched a lot without finding interesting things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of way to do the same.

1). Event - Raise event - Subscribe event mechanism.

2). Use Event Aggregator instead of traditional event delegation model.

3). Use INotifyPropertyChange or similar object to get notification on some change and do what is intented to be done.

None of them would be hard to understand, find, learn and implement.